# Изменить скрипт Javascript под мобильные экраны

Tags: jquery, html, javascript, css

Всем привет. Есть такой скрипт:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
        $('#dostavka4').each(function(){
        var imagePos = $(this).offset().top;

        var topOfWindow = $(window).scrollTop();
            if (imagePos < topOfWindow+500) {
                $(this).addClass("slideExpandUp");
            }
        });
    });
```

Я его, конечно, слябзил, но примерно работает так: если позиция объекта меньше 500px от верха экрана при скроле, то добавляем класс. Работает классно в браузере на компьютере. Но вот на мобильных устройств работает не очень, т.к. там нужно гораздо меньше, чем 500 px.
Как быть в данной ситуации? Может, придумать какой-то костыль через if?

Ссылка на сайт, где это работает [тут.](http://eurobuket.kz/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if ширина дисплея меньше чем --- выполнять один скрипт.

else --- выполнить данный скрипт.

Думаю, это самое простое решение. =)

Comment: а подскажите, как получить ширину дисплея)???

Comment: Я извиняюсь, не увидел комментарий.

    $(document).width();